# Is asking a question about the location (pg number, chapter, etc) of content in a specific book on topic?

Tags: support, on-topic

Background -- I own and have read the Curse of Strahd, and know of some information that exists within the book but cannot for the life of me remember where I read it in the book.  Short of reading the entire book again, I don't know how else I can find what I am looking for. Is it off-topic to ask where I can find this information in the book?  Will my question be downvoted into oblivion for essentially being a "read the book to me" question, despite the fact I have read the book?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it is on topic to ask along the lines of "where are the rules/content/etc for this specific thing? I know it's there but can't find it." We handle this in the [content-identification](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/content-identification) tag.

We will point you to where it is in your book, but we (likely) won't be reproducing it for you unless it'd be within fair use — that makes it not a "read the book to me" question.

A recent key example is [What D&D manual describes this game dragons play?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/84730/1204), where the querent was sure a particular form of game existed in-universe but didn't know the name or where to read about it, and both were provided along with a brief summary of the content being asked about. (This is the *Xorvintaal* question, for those who may have seen it before.)

You'll be downvoted if it's totally obvious, like if you ask where the combat rules are in a book with a big old all-caps "COMBAT RULES" entry in the table of contents, but that's normal research-effort basics.

Comment: Yeah, if it's in the index or something it'll be poorly received.  If it's really hard to find, I don't think anyone would take it awry.  But yes, don't expect content to be reproduced...

Comment: Sometimes the answer appears trivial at first blush but is complicated: Sometimes books differ from the established system how they are written like in the example of [Sword & Fan *forgetting* captions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/185045/rokugans-light-cavalry) or they never mention which book something is in and you need a totally *different* book that has a master index, like here: [What school are the Kitsune Scouts?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/166020/what-school-are-the-kitsune-scouts)